Dereference URLs in Google Cloud objects
I'm writing an application using the Google Cloud Python Client Libraries. Every so often, I encounter an object that references another via a URL. For example, the Zone object has a region field that contains a value like "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/regions/someregion".
If I have a Zone object and want to get the corresponding Region object, what do I do?
I see a few options:

Parse the URL to extract the relevant data then use the RegionClient.get method with that data.
Directly request the given URL.

At one point, I found a post suggesting that these URLs are not "real" (Sorry, can't find that post now). If true, option 2 is a non-starter. I haven't actually tried that option yet because I haven't taken the time to figure out authentication on a direct call like that.
I don't think I am the only one to notice this issue. For example, this blog post says the following in reference to storage buckets:

Strangely – given how common it is for objects to referenced by their URI – the GCS Python client library does not provide any convenience methods to automatically extract bucket and file name information from raw URIs.
Therefore, it is up to you to implement your own method to extract bucket and file names from raw URIs if you want to load objects using the Python SDK.

Parsing the URL feels a bit hacky to me, though I do see places in the SDK where paths are parsed.
Is parsing the URL the right thing to do?
I have so far been parsing the URLs. It seems to work, but as I say, it feels hacky. So I'm just looking to verify that is the right option.
EDIT:
Perhaps a better example would be if you want to find the image used to create an instance which is another real example in my application. You get the instance and you look at the disk attachments for the boot disk and the source attribute is a URL to the disk (reference). Then, you get that disk and the source_image attribute is a URL to the image (reference).
Based on input from @DazWilkin, I tried just GETting the URLs manually. I managed to accomplish it within the existing framework. In my case, I was using a service account so it looks like this:
>>> from google.oauth2 import service_account
>>> credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file, scopes=scopes)
>>> from google.cloud import compute
>>> instance_client = compute.InstancesClient(credentials=credentials)
>>> inst = instance_client.get(project='myproject', instance='myinstance', zone='myzone')
>>> inst.disks[0].source
'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/myzone/disks/mydisk'
>>> from google.auth.transport import requests as google_transport
>>> r = google_transport.Request()
>>> credentials.refresh(r)
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.get(inst.disks[0].source, headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {credentials.token}'})
>>> resp.ok
True
>>> resp.json()
{'kind': 'compute#disk', ... 'name': 'mydisk', 'sizeGb': '60', ...etc}

This shows it is possible. However, that still feels a bit strange to me. I would prefer something more direct. But, if those are the only two options, I guess that's the answer.

Generally developers interact (Cloud Console, gcloud, SDKs) with resources at an abstraction above a resource's URL/URI. There's usually a one-way function that then converts the abstract object into a specific URL. It's reasonable to expect the e.g. SDKs to make the conversion bidirectional (URL to higher-level resource) but it's uncommon. If you want to do it, then you just parse the URL. Can you provide a more specific example for why your code is receiving URLs? In your example, I think it's reasonable to assume that zone {some-region}-{x} is always going to be in region {some-region}.

Sure, maybe getting the region for a zone wasn't a great example. What if you want to find the image used to create an instance which is another real example in my application. You get the instance and you look at the disk attachments for the boot disk and the source attribute is a URL to the disk. Then, you get that disk and the source_image attribute is a URL to the image.

Ah, yes now I understand your issue, thanks! Yes, composite resources references child resources by URI (strings) rather than some composite type. I suspect (!?) the SDKs don't provide helpers for parsing these strings because (historically) Google's SDKs were machine-generated and only interested in getting from e.g. Python to the URL. I agree that it would be useful to have definitive parsers to avoid redoing|erroring but I think that's your only option.

As long as you authenticate the request, you ought be able to curl any resource URL: curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" ${RESOURCE}

Thanks, that seems like a reasonable explanation for the lack of official parsing functions. And I'll give directly requesting the URLs a try to see if I can make that work.

In your quoted text, there is no easy way to use a URl in the SDK because there are many URIs to access storage. The interface (XML/JSON) and type of authorization (public/authorized) make a difference. The URI is an identifier and not a real URI. My advice is to not follow the path you are going down with URIs until you know each interface and access method. Use either the REST JSON API, one of the official SDKs (preferred), or the XML API (for compatibility with S3/etc).

@JohnHanley I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. I am currently using the official Google Cloud Python SDK but there is no way to get the referenced object directly. I either have to parse the URI and then use the SDK methods to get the object or do a direct HTTP request (which works on at least one that I have tried but I don't expect that to always work). Are you suggesting there is a direct way to get the referenced object?

@jwrw - I am suggesting only using official SDK/REST methods and treating the URI as an opaque identifier only. In other words, do not try to obtain meaning from values that are not documented.

@JohnHanley Okay, that's reasonable. Following that advice would mean there is no way to figure out what image was used to create an instance, correct? That seems like a serious defect with the SDK/API, doesn't it?

@jwrw - A compute Engine instance is not created from an image. A Boot Disk can optionally be created from an image or snapshot. The Boot Disk is attached to an instance. Look for sourceImage in this API: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/get An important item to notice is that creating a compute engine instance involves several steps. That means you must use several APIs that work together.

Okay, sure. I simplified things a bit in my comment, sorry. But my real question is about dereferencing the URIs. For example: if I have a boot disk object that was created from an image, the sourceImage value is a URI. And according to your previous comment, there is no official way to take that URI and find the actual source image object, right? And as a developer using the SDK, that strikes me as a major defect of the SDK.
